# How to get Django Admin to display a field connected with a foreign key?

Tags: django

How to get Django display the foreign key of AnotherAim.aimid.code into one tabel of AnotherAimAdmin in the backend?

This is a classical Admin "view" separated by two different tabels in the backend:

```
class AimAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code')

# AnotherAim and AIM are connected via a foreight key

class AnotherAimAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','sur_name', 'email')
    search_fields = ['name','sur_name']


admin.site.register(Aim,AimAdmin)
admin.site.register(AnotherAim, AnotherAimAdmin)
```

My model looks like this:

```
class AnotherAim(models.Model):

    email=models.EmailField(null=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sur_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.OneToOneField(Aim,null=True)



class Aim(models.Model):

     code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)
     ....
     ....
```

Comment: Can you please post your models?

Comment: @Brandon Thanks again ;-) See my edits...this models looks a bit useless...in real its faaar bigger...totally new to admin...;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure my models as such:

```
class Aim(models.Model):
     code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.code

class AnotherAim(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sur_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    aim = models.OneToOneField(Aim, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name  # or another field
```

Comment: Thanks brandon...but how can i display it into one tabel in django admin....code an die other fields together in one list_display or so...

Comment: Are you trying to display it in the change list?

Comment: yes in the overview...i hope thats the change list...right now it displays 'name','sur_name', 'email' of the AnotherAimAdmin ModelAmin...but i want to integrate into this view the code from Aim (AimAdmin)

Comment: You can do: ['name', 'sur_name', 'email', 'aim__code'], or just [..., 'aim'] as it will return the unicode value for 'aim' which is the `code` property

Comment: That was it... somwhere i read that aim__code did not work...but i gues in django 1.5 thats possible...thanks so much....

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I know, it's been there since the newforms_admin branch.